# JNLP error opening on localhost

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Hello I created a JAVAFX application and upload the Java Websart package on my localhost server but when I was opening the app it does have an error. 
I already added the url to exception list on configure java security.
Can you help me what this errors are? When I run the JAR file that comes along with the JNLP file it execute perfectly. I think its something related to file permission?

```
Java Plug-in 11.51.2.16
Using JRE version 1.8.0_51-b16 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\yves
----------------------------------------------------
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.loadLoginScene(Unknown Source)
    at Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/27634459.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/31215714.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$34/10055096.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at Constants.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/27634459.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/31215714.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$34/10055096.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.loadLoginScene(Unknown Source)
    at Main.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at Constants.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

JNLP FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="KahayahayTaxi.jnlp">
      <information>
        <title>KahayahayTaxi</title>
        <vendor>KahayahayTaxi</vendor>
        <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>
      <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="KahayahayTaxi.jar" size="4986475" download="eager" />
        <jar href="libs/controlsfx-8.40.9.jar" size="1016589" download="eager" />
        <jar href="libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" size="876733" download="eager" />
        <jar href="libs/opencsv-3.3.jar" size="31217" download="eager" />
      </resources>
      <jfx:javafx-desc  width="0" height="0" main-class="Main"  name="KTBM Software" />
      <update check="background"/>
    </jnlp>
```

Comment: Please post your jnlp file. There is suppose to have a permission tag

Comment: Hello thank you for your interest in helping me. I edited my question please kindly take a look at it.

Comment: *"..already added the url to exception list on configure java security."*  The app. will need to be digitally signed with a valid code signing certificate before being distributed, so you might as well start doing that now.  Once the app. is properly signed and the right permissions are declared in the JNLP, use of exception lists becomes redundant.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson is there any free signing for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The security tag is:

```
<security>
   <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

Comment: Hello I added the security tag on my JNLP file but its creating new errors. It says "Found unsigned entry in resource"

Comment: You should sign your jars. There tutorials for this.